Trouble with geolocation prompt status on iPhone, Safari, Chrome on iPhone
The problem is that I cannot get geolocation status to stop being in the prompt state on iPhone.  The idea is that I want to send the long and latitude coordinates of a user only when they haven't shared their location or denied sharing their location.
This code works fine on desktop Chrome but it continuously reloads on iPhone.
I expect the prompt to ask for location, if user chooses yes then the fetch will fire off their coords and when it has done the work, it will return and reload the page.
When the user comes to the page again, it will not ask for the geolocation.
async getLocation() {
    const permissionStatus = await this.window.navigator?.permissions?.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then(permission => permission.state).catch(error => console.error(error));
    if (permissionStatus !== "granted" && permissionStatus !== "denied") { 
        const showPosition = (position: any) => {
            return fetch("/api/location/setLocation", {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude
                }),
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                },
            }).then((response) => {
                    this.window.location.reload();
            }).catch(error => console.error(error));
        };
        const handleError = (error) => {
            console.log("error: " + error.message);
        }
        this.window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, handleError);
    }
}```

